# How to show content differences in folder view?

Tags: beyondcompare

When I compare 2 folders, I want to see the differences in file contents. However, this seems impossible in Beyond COmpare v4 because the "Content Comparison" is under an uneditable "Requires Opening Files" in Settings:

[image]

I know this has been possible in the past. Am I going to have to download an older version in order to get this to work, or is there a way around it?

I'm using Beyond Compare `4.2.4 (build 22795)`.

Comment: Have you tried the venerable free WinMerge, http://winmerge.org/ , which shows differences in folders, and also allows right-clicking on files within compared folders to diff the files?

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows binary content comparison is already on because **Compare Contents** is checked. After you check **Compare Contents** and select the **Binary comparison** radio button, click OK. Content comparison results are indicated with equal or not equal buttons in the center column.

If the above steps don't work for you, please send your Beyond Compare settings to support@scootersoftware.com to investigate the issue. To save your settings to a file on Windows or Linux, open **Help > Support** and click the **Export** button. On macOS, open **Beyond Compare > Support** and click the **Export** button.

Comment: Yeah, but see how it has the hard-coded `Requires opening files:` above the binary comparison? That's the issue. **There should be an option to do a binary file comparison on 2 folders without having to open each individual file**. I mean that's a major use-case for me - when I have to re-clone my branch for some reason there's a few config files I need to replace, but because they have the same file size, BeyCom doesn't tell me which ones they are. Also, I'm fairly certain this option was available in previous versions. But thanks for the support option, maybe I'll do that if it's not clear.

Comment: Requires opening files means that Beyond Compare has to read file contents when Compare Contents is checked (indicating comparison performance is slower). It doesn't mean that you have to double click to view file contents. When Compare Contents is checked, file contents are read for comparison without requiring you double click to view file contents first. If you're still having trouble, email support@scootersoftware.com.

Comment: I believe Travis was asking about clicking on the files and having a bottom window panel showing the differences, instead of having to double click each of the files, and then close the file in order to view the differences, which takes up a lot of time. Quickly previewing it makes comparing easier and not open and close. Seems like 4 years later and this feature is still not present for an app made for comparing!